# Allow command-line tor client to accept anonymous connection from private address

Tags: configuration, torsocks

I am running the command-line tor client on OS X 10.10 and I have a short script that routes all my WiFi network connections through the SOCKS proxy where tor is listening (127.0.0.1:9050)

```
INTERFACE=Wi-Fi
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy $INTERFACE 127.0.0.1 9050 off
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate $INTERFACE on
tor -f ~/bridge.single
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate $INTERFACE off
```

Here `bridge.single` is a very basic torr config file that specifies a bridge relay to connect to and the Socks and Control ports for the tor client.

When I run this all my browser traffic goes through tor - e.g., Chrome - which I verify by going to check.torproject.org.

But, I am using a separate desktop app that also makes an internet connection and the tor client spits out the error

```
[warn] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed]
```

and my other application doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I tried changing the tor Socks port to 9052 but it didn't help and playing with some of the `ExitRelay` configuration parameters [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) but it didn't help.

Why would Chrome's requests and responses have no problem connecting but this other application gets blocked by the tor client?

I don't have access to any "network" settings on this other application but I didn't do anything special on Chrome - I just route my WiFi traffic through tor.

Various questions here didn't help.

**Update:** I tried the following: connect a second computer to ethernet and run the tor client there (and route all its ethernet traffic through tor). Then I shared this second computers connection over AirPort and connected my computer to it. The second computer has a tor IP through its browser but my computer STILL shows local IP while browsing through second computers connection!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're hitting the Tor built-in protection against requests **to private LAN addresses** through SOCKS proxy backend. Try using redsocks or something like it, but revise your config first : you're defenately routing LAN through Tor. Post your configs and scripts here, so I'll be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked into redsocks but is it available for os x? I'm not sure exactly how to set it up - if you could provide some more info on that I would really appreciate it. Is there another thing besides redsocks you would recommend? The config I am using (`bridge.single` above) is very simple: `Bridge <bridge_ip:bridge_port> <bridge_hash> SocksPort 9050 ControlPort 9051 CookieAuthentication 1`. Besides this I am just running the script I posted in my question and then launching this other application. Can you recommend something to revise in my config? Thank you!

Comment: @river_jones it can be compiled even under Windows =) yes it works on Mac OS. The config is in it's docs. If you'll have some troubles with it - just drop me a line! I'll be glad to help!